# How can i make this loop run only if the char array contains certain characters?

Tags: java, arrays

```
char[] message = input.toCharArray ();

String x = "";
String encrypted2 = "";

for (int index = 0 ; index < message.length ; index++)
{
    message [index]++;
    message [index]++;
}

String encrypted = new String (message);
```

I need the for loop to run only if the char array contains letters from A to N.

Comment: Make a boolean indicator. Iterate the array and check each char. If any of them are not the ones you want, make the indicator false. Check the indicator before running your loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need a second loop before the loop in your code:

```
boolean cond = true;
for(int i = 0; cond && i < message.length; i++) {
    if(message[i] < 'A' || message[i] > 'N')
        cond = false;
}
for (int index = 0 ; cond && index < message.length ; index++)
{
    message [index]++;
    message [index]++;
}
```

The first loop goes through and checks if all the characters are A through N, and upon finding a character that's not, stops checking the rest of the array and doesn't execute the loop.